# Prefect: Unknown work pool type 'docker'. Please choose from block, process

Tags: prefect

I am attempting to follow the tutorial in the Prefect docs and I have gotten to [the section where I need to create a docker work pool](https://docs.prefect.io/latest/tutorial/workers/#create-a-work-pool) using the following command:

```bash
prefect work-pool create --type docker my-docker-pool
```

However, upon executing this command, I see the following:

```bash
$ prefect work-pool create --type docker my-docker-pool
Unknown work pool type 'docker'. Please choose from block, process.
```

Can anyone help me understand why I am receiving this error and how to enable the `docker` worker type? I did not set up the prefect server I am connecting to but I do believe I have access to the configuration (where I suspect these things are set up, maybe?).

Thanks!